How to cinfigure Ubuntu 24.04 to suspend on lid close?
I don't understand why so much trouble to such a common action.
Loosing a lot of time with terminal commands when in version 22 all it took was 5 min. to download Gnome Tweaks.
Ubuntu 24.04 is great and I sincerely dont understand why make users press the power button to suspend then close the lid. Is this some kind of punishment?
A little humour...

Hmmm. When I close the lid of my laptop, it sleeps just like it is supposed to. Why would this need to be configured? If yours does not work, seems like a bug, and should be reported to the bug tracker.

Are you really having issues in getting your system to suspend or is this a post to express your frustration? Can you [edit] your post to clarify how you were able to configure suspend before and what doesn't work now? The issue is not quite clear right now and users may not be able to help you without additional information. Thanks!

Disabling suspend when laptop closes on Ubuntu 24.04.1 is an answer which for the alternative of how to disable suspension when the lid is closed. What is the value of HandleLidSwitch in your /etc/systemd/logind.conf file?

If Gnome Tweaks answered your question please post it as a separate answer, and specify what you did in specific detail so that users can do the same thing you did if they have the same problem.
